# Type comments for list of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-typing, pylance

Is there way for typing e.g. a list of ints without `typing`?

I use python 2.7 and there is no `typing` yet and the only way to define a type for type hints is type comments.

The goal is that PyLance would see the variables as list of integers.

```py
# python 3+
from typing import List
parameters = [] # type: List[int]

# python 2.7
parameters = [] # type: ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, type hinting through annotations is not supported. Still, you can use type comments to hint types for variables.So PyLance might recognize parameters as a list of integers

```
parameters = []  # type: list[int]
```

or

```
parameters: list[int] = []
```

Comment: It indeed works! Since I use python 2.7 only to launch the script and PyLance is using 3.11, I can use types in type comments the way they would work in Python 3.11.

Other solution I've found is to add `if sys.version >= 3: from typing import List` but using just `list` is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Python 3.9, [you can use `list` in a typing hint directly without importing `typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections).

So in Python 3.9 or later you can just write

```py
parameters = []  # type: list[int]
```

Using the comment style of type hint allows your code to potentially run under Python 2.7 as well, provided there aren't any other breaking differences. Though in new code intended for Python 3 only, it's usually preferable to use the inline syntax

```py
parameters: list[int] = []
```